# Inserting Timeline (similar to Legend) on map using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, legend, time

is there any way to insert a timeline in ArcGIS 10.1? I mean timeline more as a kind of legend showing at which time (or after how many minutes) point features occured (not animated or dynamic!).

I have plotted a number of whale blows in different colours, depending on the time they were detected. However, it doesn't show how much time there was between blows and how long the entire sighting was.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't this just be a [graph](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_are_graphs_in_ArcGIS/003300000001000000/) with a time x axis and maybe different sightings/blows as y axis?

Answer (score 1):

To do this I think you would need to look into using ArcPy to clone [text](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000000m000000) and [graphic](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000040000000) elements.

The code is far from trivial but would have much in common with the [GraphicElement example 2](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000000m000000) which is provided to "construct a graphic table based on data values from a table in the map document".

However, I suspect that you will find it much easier to write a [label expressio](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s800000027000000)n that concatenates the same data on each whale sighting next to its point location than to put it off into the map surrounds.